# SSIS derived column remove text from string, keep only numeric values

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I am trying to remove text from a specific column and only keep the numeric values. I tried to use a derived column and also tried to search for the answer, but did not find the solution.

For example, the table looks like this:

```
order_number
1001
1002 k
1003
text
1004
aa 1007
```

I hope somebody could help me with this. Thanks in advance

This is the error I get:

[image: screenshot error]

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lott @Hadi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a script component *(make sure to add an output column (outordernumber))*:

```
if(!Row.ordernumber_IsNull){
    Row.outordernumber = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Row.ordernumber, "[^0-9]", "")
}else{
    Row.outordernumber_IsNull = true;
}
```

I think you missed this step:

[image]

Package Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but i keep getting an error:

 CS1061 'Input0Buffer' does not contain a definition for 'order_number' and no accessible extension method 'order_number' accepting a first argument of type 'Input0Buffer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: also. keep in mind that these are strings and not numbers and that one that didn't have any numbers is an empty string ("") which will not convert direct to a number

Comment: thank you. I got a little bit farther. When i try to run the component, it gives me error:
[Script Component [91]] Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: It means you have nulls in your data which you didnt provide in your sample. If(row.colname.isnullorempty){row.colname="";}else{original logic}

Comment: i tried the if else statement but could not get it to work, because  if, else and isnullorempty could not get it recognized. I tried to bypass it by replacing all the nulls with "a", with derived collumn but still got the null values error i showed in the print screen before.

Comment: @user7418776 make sure to add a new output column in the script component, also you should check if the input column is null before applying any transformation. Check my update to this answer